# hissing sound coming from my car when AC is on or Off

Tags: engine

the hissing sound started yesterday when i would turn on the AC. it would stop when i turned it off. 
Now it is ongoing, even when i don't have the AC on. When i turn the car on, at first there is no hissing sound. Then it starts. Is it the engine itself?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! More than likely the AC is functioning as designed. There is an expansion valve which allows the refrigerant to expand and become cool. It will continue to hiss until the system is equalized. Maybe you didn't notice it before? I'm assuming the AC is still working?

Comment: If your AC/Heat system uses engine vacuum to actuate the mode temp and blend doors, then the vacuum switch that controls that may be leaking, or the vacuum supply line under the dash is broken before it get to the switch. Make, Model, Year and engine size?